# Page falls when it reloads and gives an ngix error

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a problem with my ReactJs. I created an app that when a user inputs a username and password, it takes him to his account that has a sidebar menu with different pages and routes. The routes work properly on the local server and when I reload each page, it reloads successfully. Yet, when I deployed my website on a testing server, it falls whenever I refresh the page and returns this error :
[image]

What could be the reason for this problem considering that it works locally with ease and the route is reloaded successfully. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: where u deployed? name of u r testing server? Have you configured your site ?

Comment: @AmareshSM Are there any specific configurations that can be done on my side. I handle the frontend part in this project so Idk what I should do. Any help?!

Comment: check this link: https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed you have to specify the  location of your project files in nginx.